# Inductive definition of boolean

Tags: coq

Trivially, I'm trying to define my own bool type as:

```
Inductive mybool : Type :=
    | true
    | false.
```

Then I do a "Print mybool." but the output says

```
Inductive mybool : Set := true : mybool | false : mybool.
```

How come the type of "mybool" is Set but not Type?

Comment: Surely, you must have done a "Print mybool".  Can you correct the question?

Answer (score 3):

Coq uses what is called "Universe Minimization" to put inductive types in the smallest possible universe. Since `mybool` doesn't depend on any other types and doesn't do any universal quantification, it can safely be put in the (second) lowest level of `Type`, which is `Set`. The lowest level is `Prop`, but inductive types are only placed in `Prop` if they only have one constructor (there are some exceptions to this), or if it's explicitly annotated.

Note that Coq's universes are cumulative, so `mybool` is really in every level of `Type`, but it only shows the minimal level.

Comment: I thought Set is the lowest leve of Type. and Second lowest is Prop (Prop is higher than Set).  I thought Prop is for propositions.  In my bool, we have two constructors.  Not sure I understand this part.

Comment: @ShuhengZheng `Prop` indeed is for propositions, and can be thought of as types that have at most one element. That means that `Prop` doesn't contain "large" types that are normally found in `Set`, like `nat` or `bool`. But on the other hand, everything in `Prop` fits in `Set`, so `Prop` is a lower level than `Set`. You can check this with something like `Axiom P: Prop. Check P: Set.` (which works) vs `Axiom P: Set. Check P: Prop.` (which doesn't).

Comment: Note also there is `Unset Universe Minimization ToSet `